# autocomplete not accepting the json object for source

Tags: javascript, ajax, liferay-6, jquery-autocomplete

Below is the jsp page tag for input text element:

```
<input name="searchTextSpan" id="searchTextSpan" type="text"/>
```

below is the ajax call that loads on dcument.ready:

```
AUI().use("liferay-portlet-url", function(A) {
    var resourceURL = Liferay.PortletURL.createResourceURL();
    resourceURL.setPortletId("app_war_portlet");
    resourceURL.setResourceId(resourceId);
    require(["dojo/request", "dijit/registry", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"], function(request){
          request.post(resourceURL.toString(), {
              query: ajaxData,
              handleAs: "json"
          }).then(function(data){
              if(resourceId == 'inputTextClick'){
                  AUI().use("liferay-portlet-url", function(A) {
                        var resourceURL =   Liferay.PortletURL.createResourceURL();
                            resourceURL.setPortletId("app_war_portlet");
                        if(data.cachetmpArr!=null && data.cachetmpArr.length>0){
                            var cacheList = JSON.stringify(data.cachetmpArr);
                            cacheList = cacheList.replace(/"/g, "'");
                            console.log('cacheList12 '+cacheList);//['106182233','206182233','306182233'];
                                     $('#searchTextSpan').autocomplete({
                                                width: 300,
                                                max: 10,
                                                delay: 100,
                                                minLength: 1,
                                                autoFocus: true,
                                                cacheLength: 1,
                                                scroll: true,
                                                highlight: false,
                                                source:cacheList,
                                             }).focus(function(){
                                             $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
                                             });
                        }
                  });

              }

          });
    })
})
```

the source attribute is not accepting the cacheList  it throws 404 url error.
can you please suggest

Comment: I don't think you are even getting the JSON. So you may need to debug why the call to server fails.

Comment: i do get the json object value console.log('cacheList12 '+cacheList);//['106182233','206182233','306182233']; this is what i get. in case i give the value like cacheList=['106182233','206182233','306182233'], it works! but passing the objec directly it doesnt pick up

Comment: okay. Then you need to parse your JSON before you pass it to autocomplete.  `JSON.parse(cacheList)`. Remember, JSON is a `string`, whereas autocomplete needs an `array`

Answer (score 0):

You need to `parse` JSON before you pass it to `autocomplete`.

Like this:

```
$('#searchTextSpan').autocomplete({                                               


 width: 300,
    max: 10,
    delay: 100,
    minLength: 1,
    autoFocus: true,
    cacheLength: 1,
    scroll: true,
    highlight: false,
    source:JSON.parse(cacheList), // parse JSON response
    }).focus(function(){
    $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
});
```

Comment: i dont get any error , but there is no dropdown visible for my previous searched records :( also if i log this console.log('vals '+JSON.parse(cacheList)); it give me blank....

Comment: Also, any reason you are using the `focus` method? can you try removing it?

Comment: yes i tried removing focus method as well, still there is no drop down visible for the previous searched values..

Comment: What do you mean by previous searched values?

Comment: console.log('cacheList12 '+cacheList);//['106182233','206182233','306182233'];  this will have the values that has been searched, next time i type in my input text box like say 10.... i should get in the drop-down as 106182233 that will be  there in my previous searched cachelist that is parsed to source.